pass value of a variable with the same name between procedures/functions in Scheme
I want to pass values of variable with the same name (say "bindings") between procedures, but have problems with it. For example, I have several procedures like the one below, they all have the variable "bindings":
(define (foo bindings)
 (cond   ((condition1)  (bar bindings))
         ((condition2)  (cat bindings))
         (else   (foo (cdr (bindings))))))

I have procedures foo, bar and cat print "bindings" before and after execution, found the value of bindings did not pass out of the procedure, should I define a globle variable "bindings"?
before foo, bindings: ()
  before bar, bindings: ()
  after bar, bindings: (blablabla)
after foo, bindings: ()
before foo, bindings: ()
  before cat, bindings: ()
  after cat, bindings: (cilicilicili)
after foo, bindings: ()

the result I want is (blablabla, cilicilicili). What should I do?
Thank you very much.
I use online environment on https://try.scheme.org/

Procedure arguments are local to the procedure (giving two things the same name does not make them the same thing). You should return a value from your procedures. There are excellent books in Scheme online; here and here.

The same concept is true in most programming languages.

Please add all the functions and show where you have the print statements. It sounds like you already have a global variable bindings.

Scheme doesn't have pass-by-reference, only pass-by-value. To update a list from a called function, the update has to come at the caller level with what comes back from the function (return value).  (append... ) the output from bar and cat to a list in foo.

Well... You can use boxed values or something, but a better program design is preferable.
